# publish google play with password resctriction

Tags: publish, google-play, password-protection

I would like to publish an app in google play, but I want to restrict the downloading under password or something like that. Is it possible? Is there any alternative?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short Answer:*

No.

*Slightly Long Answer:*

Applications available on Google Play cannot be downloaded only **after** a user authenticates. Any such feature will have to be implemented withing **your** application. At best, if this feature is needed for monetary reasons, publish a paid application.

Since the OP isn't descriptive beyond what you are looking for as a feature, it will be difficult to suggest an option / alternative that *might* suit your requirement. However, if you have a server setup that can communicate with the app, you can implement a feature which requires users, upon installation and running your app, to *Sign Up* for a new account and/or *Login* if already registered.

Again, I will circle back to the original point. Any such feature will have to implemented **within** the application **itself**. Google Play does **not** have such a feature.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. I want protect to avoid someone another company decompile and copy my code. I'll try to obfuscate my code

Comment: You can't prevent decompiling Android APK, but you can increase the difficulty of decompilation. Try to use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) from Google that shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer. Because ProGuard makes your application harder to reverse engineer.